# Community College Math Prof. Prospect

Tags: mathematics, teaching, tenure-track, community-college

Where can I find reliable statistics/info on the outlook of tenure math teaching jobs at the community college level? Teaching is my biggest reward, I love math, and I refuse to enter industry (but I also don't think I will do a postdoc).

I'm seriously considering entering this profession after the PhD (I'm currently a 3rd year math Phd student), but I am not sure what to expect. I.e., I am not sure how much pressure there will be for me to be forced to accept adjunct roles with no hope of tenure or security of employment. I was told that my old community college, which has 10,000 students, hasn't hired a tenure track math professor since 2009, and I am not sure how common this trend is. I am willing to move.

Comment: I'm not sure what statistics would tell you. There are enormous variations according to time and place. For example, there was basically no tenure-track faculty hiring (even to replace people retiring) at my community college in California ca. 2008-2012, because of the state budget crisis during those years. But now we're hiring people by the boatload. Statistics also may be unhelpful because not all applicants are equally qualified. Many CC faculty apps simply show that the applicant didn't care much about the job. Some math depts prefer PhDs, some prefer a master's in math education.

Comment: For general issues involving teaching in community colleges (in the U.S.A.), *The Chronicle of Higher Education* has a lot of useful articles.

Comment: At my college, full-time Instructors in good standing earn tenure after four years. Assuming the future resembles the past, you can more or less ascertain the rate that those positions are filled by checking the faculty roster on a departmental web site. For example, my wife's department has sixty full-timers, whose careers might be thirty years each, so they hire about two a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community colleges are organized differently between the states, but here's where you can find the current job listings in California, the biggest state:

https://www.cccregistry.org/jobs/searchForm.aspx

You'll have to do some reading (I got five pages of results for "mathematics"), but some of these positions are clearly tenure-track, and some are clearly not. In my district, the SFCCD, all the full-time faculty positions are inherently tenure-track.